# Get Access violation reading location 0x000000b0 with glutMouseFunc

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, access-violation

I'm using glutMouseFunc(mouseFunction); as a callback however I keep getting the Access violation reading location 0x000000b0 at this line glutMouseFunc(mouseFunction);

I'm not using any of the glutInit functions because they interfere with the program and they are not essential anyways.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error when at this callback?

Here is my initialize function:

```
   int Initialize()
   {
      /* Bunch of code here that is irrelevant to the problem.......*/
      glutMouseFunc(mouseFunction); // Error occurs here.
   }
```

And here is my mouseFunction:

```
    void mouseFunction(int button, int state, int x, int y){
      if(button==GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN) 
          {
               printf("Pressed middle mouse button!");
          }
      }
```

I've noticed one thing though, there error does not occur when I call the mouseFunction() as a normal function call in my Initialize method however once I try to use the mouseFunction with glutMouseFunc(mouseFunction), than the error happens so I believe this is more of an error with glutMouseFunc.

Comment: *I'm not using any of the glutInit functions because they interfere with the program and they are not essential anyways.* Er, what!

Comment: What is the content of the call stack at the crash? Probably in GLUT since you didn't bother to set it up properly and then it explodes.

Comment: What I mean is glutCreateWindow for the most part interferes so I just leave it out.

Comment: What does *interferes* mean? And how can you have mouse events without a window?

Comment: It is being done externally through another class. When I put glutCreateWindow, it stops the Window from actually coming up since the window is appearing from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comments to the other questions your problem is simply, that you call `glutMouseFunc` without a GLUT window. Trying to register GLUT event callbacks without proper initialization or without a GLUT window created *will* crash your program.

You also say "GLUT interferes" with your actual window. So why would you try to register a GLUT callback at all if you don't have a window that could actually receive the events for GLUT to dispatch?

You should use the mouse event handling of the window you've already got. And what are you using GLUT for then anyway? The whole purpose of GLUT is to create a window for you and do event management. If you don't use GLUT for that, then don't use GLUT at all.

If it's for the teapot, well, you can have that without GLUT as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was the most useful information I've gotten that was basically stating the obvious. I'll try to go on another route with this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not using any of the glutInit functions because they interfere with the program and they are not essential anyways.

This is your problem. If you're going to use GLUT, use it correctly.

The `glutInit()` function **is** essential - part of what it does is initializing internal state within GLUT. As you've discovered, with this state not properly initialized, other parts of GLUT (such as mouse event handling!) may not work properly.

Comment: OK but when I used glutInit() function with the appropriate parameters, I still get the same result...